# CentOS 6 not displaying

Tags: centos, virtualbox, centos6.5

I installed CentOS on Oracle VirtualBox and it run perfectly fine on command line but then I installed desktop environment by typing the following command:
yum groupinstall "X windows system" "KDE Desktop", edit the initdefault id from 3 (command line) to 5 (GUI), save the file and reboot the system but it doesn't display the login screen, in fact it hangs on loading. . Please help me out in this.

I can't attach the image as the message pops up stating that i need at least 10 reputation to post images...

I will write down the last two lines when it hangs..

```
Starting postfix :      [OK]
Starting httpd:         [OK]
Starting crond:         [OK]
```

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you switch to a TTY (ex: Right Ctrl + F3), login and run `startx`?

Comment: @Salem Did you mean `alt` or `ctrl-alt` there?

Comment: hostname: unknown host

xinit: no such file or directory (errno 2): no server "/usr/bin/X" in PATH
xinit: Connection refused (errno 111): unable to connect to X server
xinit: No such process  (errno 3): Server error.

Comment: @EtanReisner Ctrl+alt+F3 would change TTY on the host system (if running Linux). To change it in the VM you have to use the Right Ctrl.

Comment: @FurqanKhan Check again if X was installed with `yum groupinstall "X Window System"`. BTW you are really using the VM (ie you are typing those commands in VirtualBox window) or you are connected to the VM by SSH?

Comment: @Salem thanks a lot, its working now. I guess it's case sensitive, prolly that's why it didn't work the first time or might be spelling error.. i am using oracle vm virtualbox GUI 4.3 manager.
Thanks again..

Comment: I'll admit to not being a virtualbox user but I don't understand how it could make `ctrl-f3` do what `ctrl-alt-f3` does normally without stealing `ctrl-f#` keypresses from X entirely (which would be a somewhat horrible thing to do) but <shrug>.

Comment: @EtanReisner That only happens when your VM has focus. If you press Right Ctrl+F, that is sent to Virtualbox and it toggles between windowed and fullscreen mode. The same happens with Ctrl+Fx, as your VM has focus VirtualBox grabs that combination, and translates that to Ctrl+Alt+Fn to the running VM.

Comment: I was talking about virtualbox stealing `ctrl-f#` from the guest, not the host. `ctrl-f#` is a useful set of key combinations to have available and globally stealing them from all guest applications seems like a poor idea when you could just not do that and pass them (and the `ctrl-alt-F#` combinations) through unmolested. Does virtualbox use `ctrl-alt-f#` for itself for something?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some `yum` commands are case sensitive (atleast `install` and `groupinstall`), so the correct command is

```
$ yum groupinstall "X Window System" "KDE Desktop"
```